# Не создаётся директория на андроид

Tags: java, android, файлы, файловая-система

При попытке создать директорию

```
filePath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

возвращает False.
Разрешения в Manifest даны

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

При нажатии на кнопку динамически проверяется присутствие разрешения.
Собственно сам код:

```
case R.id.buttonCreateWaybill:
                if ((checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
                HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("test");
                File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Waybills", "demo.xls");
                try {
                    if (!filePath.getParentFile().exists()) {
                        filePath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    }
                    if (!filePath.exists()) {
                        filePath.createNewFile();
                    }
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                    workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
                    if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                        fileOutputStream.flush();
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
                break;
```

Comment: На какой версии Андроид запускаете данный код?

Comment: api 30, 11 версия

Comment: В андроид 11 [поменялся](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) подход работы с external storage, теперь нужно использовать [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage)

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё заработало.